# New-AzWebAppBackup: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, backup

When I'm trying to execute the Azure App Service Backup over Azure Powershell with `New-AzWebAppBackup` cmdlet as described here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/New-AzWebAppBackup?view=azps-3.3.0

I'm getting the following error message:

```
PS Azure:\> New-AzWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "MyWebApp" -StorageAccountUrl "https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/"
New-AzWebAppBackup : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzWebAppBackup], DefaultErrorResponseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.NewAzureWebAppBackup
```

[image: Azure Powershell Screenshot]

Does anyone know what I'm missing? I'm thankful for any advice. Many Thanks.

Comment: impossible to tell, add `-Debug` and provide the request being sent and an actual answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Hope your webapp satisfies the prerequisites to be able to take a backup. The Backup and Restore feature requires the App Service plan to be in the **Standard** tier or **Premium** tier. Refer to [Requirements and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup#requirements-and-restrictions) for the complete details.

I got the same error initially when executing the cmdlet. However, passing the `-debug` switch with the cmdlet helped me understand the error better:

```
{
 "ErrorEntity": {
 "ExtendedCode": "04205",
 "MessageTemplate": "The provided URI is not a SAS URL for a container (it needs to be https and it has to have 2 segments).",
 "Parameters": [],
 "Code": "BadRequest",
 "Message": "The provided URI is not a SAS URL for a container (it needs to be https and it has to have 2 segments)."
}
```

The `-StorageAccountUrl` parameter expects a SAS URL to be passed (refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/backup#request-body) doc). The SAS URL for your Storage account is of the format:

```
sasurl=https://$storagename.blob.core.windows.net/$container$sastoken
```

To generate the SAS token, run the following:

```
# Retrieve one of the Storage Account keys
$key = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "<rg-name>" -AccountName "<storage-account-name>").Value[0]

# Populate the Storage Account context
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<storage-account-name>" -StorageAccountKey $key

# Generate the SAS token
$sastoken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name "<container-name>" -Permission rwdl -Context $ctx

# Generate the SAS URL
$sasurl = "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>$sastoken"

# Create a backup
New-AzureRmWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName "<rg-name>" -Name "<app-name>" -StorageAccountUrl $sas -BackupName "<backup-name>"
```

Successful execution of the above commands should let you create the backup. The response would look something like this:
[image: webapp backup]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi :-) PERFECT! Many Thanks. That really helped me out and is working perfectly. Just to let you and all other possible users know there is a typo in the last command with the $sasurl. OLD: New-AzureRmWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName "<rg-name>" -Name "<app-name>" -StorageAccountUrl $sas -BackupName "<backup-name>" NEW: New-AzureRmWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName "<rg-name>" -Name "<app-name>" -StorageAccountUrl $sasurl -BackupName "<backup-name>"

Comment: @JAST Ah, good catch, thanks! Glad to know it helped you out. :)

Comment: @JAST Looks like there was an edit conflict. Please feel free to resubmit the edit. ;)